# how to get UTC offset value from timezone?

Tags: django, python-2.7

In my Django project, I have a form ***(forms.py)*** which implements pytz to get current timezone like this:

```
tz = timezone.get_current_timezone()
```

and I have passed this value to a form field as an initial value like this:

```
timezone = forms.CharField(label='Time Zone', initial=tznow)
```

which gives the field a default value of current Timezone, in my case, it happens to be **Asia/Calcutta**.

Now i want to find the UTC Offset value for the given Timezone, which in this case **Asia/Calcutta** is **+5:30**

I tried tzinfo() method as well, but i couldn't find the expected result. Can somebody guide me through this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The UTC offset is given as a timedelta by the utcoffset method of any implementation of tzinfo such as pytz. For example:

```
import pytz
import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')
dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

offset_seconds = tz.utcoffset(dt).total_seconds()

offset_hours = offset_seconds / 3600.0

print "{:+d}:{:02d}".format(int(offset_hours), int((offset_hours % 1) * 60))
# +5:30
```

Comment: Thanks man. When i print offset_hours it gives: 5.5 & its a float type.

now how do change it to +5.5 without changing it's type ?

Comment: (1) it is incorrect to pass UTC time to `tz.utcoffset()` unless `tz = pytz.utc` (2) `.seconds` is wrong for negative offsets (`.days` is `-1`) (3) No need to use floats here (use `divmod()`).

Answer (score 5):

A single timezone such as `Asia/Calcutta` may have different utc offsets at different dates. You can enumerate the utc offsets known so far using `pytz`'s `_tzinfos` in this case:

```
>>> offsets = {off for off, dst, abbr in pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')._tzinfos}
>>> for utc_offset in offsets:
...     print(utc_offset)
... 
5:30:00
6:30:00
5:53:00
```

To get the current utc offset for a given timezone:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

utc_offset = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')).utcoffset()
print(utc_offset)
# -> 5:30:00
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you just want the normalized hour offset:

```
def curr_calcutta_offset():
    tz_calcutta = pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')
    offset = tz_calcutta.utcoffset(datetime.utcnow())
    offset_seconds = (offset.days * 86400) + offset.seconds
    offset_hours = offset_seconds / 3600

    return offset_hours

curr_calcutta_offset()
# 5.5
```