# How to obtain only utcoffset value from pytz timezone?

Tags: django, python-2.7, pytz

How can i obtain only the **UTCOFFSET** value from the `pytz.timezone()` function without using `localize()` method?

eg: 
    `pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')` gives:

```
DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' LMT+5:53:00 STD
```

Here i want to get only the **LMT+5:53** as value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get UTC offset value from timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563277/how-to-get-utc-offset-value-from-timezone)

Comment: The Above thread was created by me only, which uses datetime.datetime.utcnow() to get the localize() timestamp and respected utcoffset. Here i only require the LMT+5:53 value. Not the +5:30 which is the local offset for me, which happens to be 'Asia/Calcutta'. Is there any option i can retrieve that value using some class atrributes?

Comment: pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta').zone gives the zone value, what gives the offset value ?

Comment: Each timezone name (e.g. `Asia/Calcutta`) corresponds to a history of possibly
many timezone abbreviations and offsets. `LMT+5:53` was the timezone and offset in
Calcutta before `1901-12-13 20:45:52`. Currently Calcutta is in `IST+0530`. Do you
always want the first abbreviation and offset in the database?

Comment: `LMT+5:53` is not a utc offset. What value do you want to get? In what context it is used?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face isn't as simple as getting the UTCOFFSET from the pytz.timezone object because the answer depends on WHEN you are talking about.

For instance, if I want to know the UTCOFFSET of central timezone (US) *right now*, the answer is GMT-6.  But if we were in daylight savings time the answer would be GMT-5.  So WHEN matters!

---

I used something like this to get my the tzinfo object for each timezone in standard time.  From there, I think you can grab the attributes that you want of the tzinfo.

```
def getPytzInSTD(tname):
    """
    This returns a pytz timezone object normalized to standard time for the zone requested.
    If the zone does not follow DST or a future transition time cannot be found, it normalizes to NOW instead.

    :param tname:  Proper timezone name found in the tzdatabase. example: "US/Central"
    """

    # This defaults to the STD time for the zone rather than current time which could be DST
    tzone = pytz.timezone(tname)
    NOW = datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC)
    std_date = NOW
    hasdst = False
    try:
        #transitions are in UTC.  They need to be converted to localtime once we find the correct STD transition.
        for utcdate, info in zip(tzone._utc_transition_times, tzone._transition_info):
            utcdate = utcdate.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
            utcoffset, dstoffset, tzname = info
            if dstoffset == ZERO:
                std_date = utcdate
            if utcdate > NOW:
                hasdst = True
                break
    except AttributeError:
        std_date = NOW
    if not hasdst:
        std_date = NOW
    std_date = tzone.normalize(std_date)
    return std_date.tzinfo
```

Comment: (0) There might be more than one standard time depending on WHEN as you say e.g., Europe/Moscow in 2010-2015.  (1) you should use `.astimezone(tzone)`, to convert a utc time to `tzone` time zone instead of `tzone.normalize()` -- the result is the same in this case but `normalize()` has a different purpose and therefore your code communicates a wrong intent here. (2) Test the presence of `_utc_transition_times` attributes directly -- `AttributeError` may catch too much in your case. (3) `hasdst` name seems bogus. There could be utc transitions that are unrelated to DST.

Comment: Are there such things as a utc transition unrelated to DST?

Comment: This is really helpful !

Comment: @MarcelWilson: yes, there are. It seems you are aware of `pytz`. You could use it to find utc transitions unrelated to DST yourself (search for transitions where `dstoffset` is the same on both sides of the transition).